# How to import a document with sentences to train a doc2vec model?

Tags: python, gensim, cosine-similarity, doc2vec, sentence-similarity

i want to get the cosine similarity between sentences. I have tested doc2vec with gensim and trained it with only few sentences given in the code. But I want to train my model using a text document that have one sentence per each line. How can I use a document with sentences?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

If your document is already in the form of a text file, with one-sentence-per-line, then many of the examples included with gensim (or elsewhere) show how to handle such a corpus.

For example, there's an introductory Doc2Vec tutorial notebook bundled with `gensim` in its `docs/notebooks` directory, which you can also view online at the project github repository:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/doc2vec-lee.ipynb

Its cell (3) shows, and cell (4) uses, a function to read a file line-by-line, and turn it into the `TaggedDocument` texts that the model requires.

Comment: Thank You very much @gojomo